How to sign transaction message using new web3.js
How do I sign a transaction message using the new web3.js library
const transactionMessageTwo = pipe(
    createTransactionMessage({ version: 0 }),
    (tx) =>
        setTransactionMessageFeePayer(address(signer.publicKey.toString()), tx),
    (tx) => setTransactionMessageLifetimeUsingBlockhash(latestBlockhash, tx)
);

const signedTransaction = await signTransaction([], transactionMessage);

The Typescript Langauge server in VS code shows this error
Argument of type 'Readonly<{ instructions: readonly IInstruction<string, readonly (IAccountMeta<string> | IAccountLookupMeta<string, string>)[]>[]; version: 0; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Readonly<{ messageBytes: TransactionMessageBytes; signatures: SignaturesMap; }>'.
  Type 'Readonly<{ instructions: readonly IInstruction<string, readonly (IAccountMeta<string> | IAccountLookupMeta<string, string>)[]>[]; version: 0; }>' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<{ messageBytes: TransactionMessageBytes; signatures: SignaturesMap; }>': messageBytes, signaturests(2345)

When running the snippet above I get this
169 |   Object.freeze(out);
170 |   return out;
171 | }
172 | function assertTransactionIsFullySigned(transaction) {
173 |   const missingSigs = [];
174 |   Object.entries(transaction.signatures).forEach(([address, signatureBytes]) => {
               ^
TypeError: Object.entries requires that input parameter not be null or undefined
      at assertTransactionIsFullySigned (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-web3/node_modules/@solana/transactions/dist/index.node.mjs:174:10)
      at /home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-web3/node_modules/@solana/transactions/dist/index.node.mjs:168:3

Bun v1.1.33 (Linux x64)


You need to compile the transaction first:
const transaction = compileTransaction(transactionMessage);
const signedTransaction = signTransaction([yourKeypair], transaction)

Note that signTransaction requires the resulting transaction to be fully signed, you may need partiallySignTransaction instead.
Alternatively you can use the Signers API:
// assuming you have a cryptoKey already
const signer = await createSignerFromKeyPair(cryptoKey)

const transactionMessage = pipe(
    createTransactionMessage({ version: 0 }),
    (tx) =>
        setTransactionMessageFeePayerSigner(signer, tx),
    (tx) => setTransactionMessageLifetimeUsingBlockhash(latestBlockhash, tx)
);

const signedTransaction = signTransactionMessageWithSigners(transactionMessage)
// or again partiallySignTransactionMessageWithSigners

